# how can I add number lines to a file with in this script

Tags: linux

So I have this script file that automatically saves the date and time to a file when the terminal is open. But i'm having a hard time putting number lines in it. I tried cat -n, grep -n, ls -l, but I either get errors or doesn't increment. As you can see:

## My Script

```
echo $(date) >> .test
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
0 : Tue Feb 15 13:10 EST 2014

1 : Tue Feb 18 12:10 EST 2014

2 : Tue Feb 18 10:10 EST 2014

3 : Tue Feb 19 13:22 EST 2014
```

Comment: What do you mean by number line? Could you show an example what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you all for the very helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

`echo $(wc -l < filename) : $(date) >> filename`

Answer (score 2):

If you pipe the result into `cat`, you can use the `-n` option to number each line like so:

```
ls | grep "whatever" | cat -n
```

Comment: From his questions, it seems he's already tried that. The problem with that approach is that he is trying to increment the number every time he runs the command, not numbering each line of the output.

Comment: @ZhehaoMao - If the timestamps are already in the file then this would add the line numbers, however, I understand what you mean if he is trying to AI.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the last number in a file. Then, in your script, read in the number, increment it, and write it back to the file. If you are using bash, something like this should work.

```
num=$(cat number.txt)
num=$(($num+1))
echo $num > number.txt
```